# Remove lines from file that contain strings that match filenames in folder

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a `input.txt` file with lines representing some commands, each with two input arguments:

```
commands a b 
commands a c
commands b c 
...
```

And I want to remove all lines for which there is a match (output file) in folder `out`. For instance, imagine that only files `out/a_b_out` and `out/b_c_out` exist. Then I would like to remove the first and third line from `input.txt`.

Moreover, there could be millions of files in `out`, so I need an efficient way to look for matches. On the other hand, the number of lines in `input` is on the order of few thousands, much more manageable.

I have tried to first extract the patterns from the input file (e.g. `cut -d " " -f 2-3 input.txt | sed -e 's/\ /_/g'`), and then looping over these entries and using grep etc.

I was wondering if there is a faster and more elegant way to perform this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might work for your case

```
while read c x y; 
do [ -f "out/${x}_${y}_out" ] || echo "$c" "$x" "$y" 
done < input
```

will iterate the shorter input file and filter the lines based on existing files; the output will be the commands where the files are not found.  If your input file is not well formed you may need to strengthen read command.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Unless you need `awk` for additional processing or you need to preserve input lines exactly as-is in terms of whitespace, consider [karakfa's helpful shell-only solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799812/45375).</sup>

An `awk` solution:

Given that there can be millions of files in `out/`, building an index of filenames is not an option, but you can defer to the shell to test file existence.

This will be slow, because a `sh` child process is created for each input line, but may be acceptable with input on the order of a few thousand lines:

```
awk '{ fpath = "out/" $2 "_" $3 "_out"; if (1 == system("[ -f '" fpath "' ]")) print }' \
  input.txt > input.tmp.$$.txt && mv input.tmp.$$.txt input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

See this small test with awk (if awk is on the game) that does the opposite (just for testing):

```
$ cat file3
commands a b 
commands a c
commands b c

$ ls -l *_out
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 15 04:02 a_b_out
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 15 04:05 b_c_out

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2 "_" $3 "_out"]=$0;next}($0 in a){print a[$0]}' file3 <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf %f\\n)
commands b c
commands a b
```

Meaning that this inverted command should give you the results you need:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2 "_" $3 "_out"]=$0;next}(!($0 in a)){print a[$0]}' inuutfile <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf %f\\n) >newfile
```

You can remove the maxdepth 1 to go inside all subdirectories.

This solution builts an index based on the small input file and not on the million of files that may exist in out;thus performance is expected to be good enough.

Sending the non matching results to a new file will be much faster than continuously overwritting the existed file.

You can just move newfile over oldfile when you are done (`mv newfile inputfile`)

Comment: @retrot Answer updated - now should be fine with awk

Comment: While you're not building an _index_ from the millions of files, you're still looping over all of them, which is not a good idea.